# How to change the selection handle color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

In Flutter, when you select text, two blue dots appear at the beginning and end of the selection. I'd like to change these dots to grey.

What I mean is this:

[image]

Do I need to edit this line?:

```
selectionHandleColor: Colors.grey,
```

Can I achieve this by editing the `selectionHandleColor` property within `TextSelectionTheme`? If so, what value should I use to set the color to grey?

**Here's the relevant part of my code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextSelectionTheme(
      data: TextSelectionTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        selectionHandleColor: Colors.grey, 
      ),
      child: TextField(/* ... */),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on android/emulator device?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an android device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the textfield with a Theme widget. And in data add

```
ThemeData.light().copyWith(
  textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.green,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
  accentColor: Colors.green,
  textSelectionColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5),
  textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.green,
);
```